# Footer's background gets cut off when viewing the site on mobiles

Tags: html, iphone, css, webkit

I'm working on this new site, and something weird happens when I open the site on a mobile phone (same thing happens on iphone and android)

The website is not responsive, and when someone visits the webpage from a mobile device the footer's background is only as wide as the original viewport - which  means that most of the footer has no background (which makes text unreadable)

the URL is: http://www.wholesomegifts.com.au/ (visit it on your mobile, go down to the footer and swipe right to see the problem)

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I ended up working around the problem, by replacing width:100% with min-width:960px .....   but i still don't understand how come the background color wasn't getting the full width as it was supposed to

Answer (score 1):

Workaround -

I set the DIVs to min-width:960px - an ugly hack but did the trick.

I still don't understand why the background didn't stretch in the first place, so if anyone can shed some light on the subject that would be great

Answer (score 0):

I believe its viewport issue, Try adding this in 'head' tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

refer this link for more on this
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/